# Properties keep driving me crazy. Can't save it! "FileNotFound"

Tags: java, android, properties, save, store

these properties keep driving me crazy. I'm reading everywhere, that even loading the properties should be no problem by just using:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(new FileInputStream("filename.properties");
```

Though in my case it doest work. Java is not finding the file, which is located in the class directory! Thats why i HAD TO use it with the Assetmanager:

```
String defaultProfileProperties = "filename.properties";
Resources resources = this.getResources();
AssetManager assetManager = resources.getAssets();
final Properties properties = new Properties();

try {
    InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open(defaultProfileProperties);
    properties.load(inputStream);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Failed to open " + defaultProfileProperties + " property file");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Putting the filename.properties in the assets-folder.

Well, now I simply can't save the properties-file by using .store(out,comment) ...
I tried using a FileOutputStream with the path set to either "filename.properties", or "assets/filename.properties". Neither of them worked. I even added a slash here and there, but nothing is helping! I'm not finding any tutorials on the web, nor ppl having the same problem!

Could you please just help me? I guess this is such a simple thing, but i'm not getting a clue how to ... blah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open a file with FileInputStream, then the starting directory (relative path) is based on the working directory when you started java, NOT the classpath.  Opening a file with resources will reference the classpath entries.

Have you tried using a full path when using FileInputStream()?  Try that and see if it works, and if it does, then you'll need to either set the working directory at start up and/or reference your file via relative path from the start directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("filename.properties");
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.load(in);
```